# Reversed Language of a Non Regular Language

Tags: automata

Is the following saying true or false? In any case why?
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

- Consider the following language: 
  $$ X = \{ a^pb\Sigma^* \mid p \text{ is a prime number} \} \cup \{\Sigma^*ba^q \mid q \text{ is not a prime number}\}. $$
- Is it regular or non-regular?
- Can you find an element $x \notin X$? How $x^R$ does look like?
- Can you modify it so it would have the desired property?
- Intuitively harder, but technically simpler version can be made of the complement of language $Y = \{a^nb^n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$